# InfoPath 2007 & Sharepoint 2007

Tags: infopath

How do I display the certain field values that were entered into an InfoPath form template from SharePoint form library, as columns in a sharepoint form library or list?  I want to create views based on specific entries in a form....how is this done?

Answer (score 0):

You need to Promote those fields in the InfoPath form to SharePoint columns in the list by going to Tools->Form Options->Property Promotion and then click Add... to select which fields to have populate into the list.

Answer (score 0):

**Promoting the right columns**

There are two ways to get form fields to become Sharepoint columns.

- Click "Publish Form Template..." and then click next until you get a list of items with the option of "Add...", "Remove", or "Modify". This is the 6th screen in the publishing wizard. Click "Add..", select a field you want to add as a column, change the Column Name if you like, and then click "OK".
- Go to the **Tools** menu, click on **Form Options** and then click on Property Promotion in the list on the left side. This is the same list as found in the publishing wizard. Follow the same steps as above to add a field as a column.

**Editing a view**

After you publish the form with this change, click on the "View" dropdown in a Sharepoint List or Document Library to select the view you'd like to add new columns to and then click "Modify this View". Next, click on the checkbox in the "Display" column to make the newly created columns visible. After clicking "OK", your new columns should be visible in the view.

Comment: Thanks this did the trick but I noticed that it only makes values from the infopath form fields appear in columns if its a newly created form - it doesn't allow the field values from existing forms to populate the column (even though the columns were visible before).  I had a problem with the values not showing up in the visible column due to a mis-calculation on the column.  The column displays correctly in new forms but not in previous created forms.  I will post a new question about this.

Comment: I'm glad that helped. I don't think the values for previously posted forms will show up. The new columns added only affect new forms. A new question would be the best way to get an answer to that question. :)